# Apple Watch Simulation Won't Run After Renaming Project

Tags: ios, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I developed my app before finalizing the name. I have since gone in and renamed it to the new desired name but my watch simulation will no longer launch. I've tried Resetting Contents and Settings on the Simulator. Deleted derived data. Clean Build. Reboot.

I get the following error:

```
NewAppName WatchKit Extension[23618:294052] WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class '_TtC31Old_AppName_WatchKit_Extension19InterfaceController' to instantiate
```

Answer (score 0):

This situation happened to me, too. I simply removed the [AppName]Test target (means the test target created for your app by Xcode), and then simulator ran, and then everything was correct.

So remove the test target. This may help you.